# JMeter Basic Authentication

Tags: jmeter, authorization, http-authentication

I am trying to imply the basic authentication process for a web service using JMeter. But everytime it throws out an error 401:Unauthorized. I tried using the HTTP Header manager to add a header Authorization and value to it. Still it does not work. I have also tried using the HTTP Authorization manager. Still no luck. Can someone help.

Comment: As of JMeter 4.0, you can use either Http Authorization Manager or JSR223 PreProcessor like explained here: https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/04/24/jmeter-basic-authentication/

Answer (score 63):

I've found through debugging requests coming in from JMeter that the HTTP Authorization Manager module doesn't encode the username and password correctly. It puts a newline character after the username.

To run a JMeter test against a Basic Auth protected endpoint, include the HTTP Header Manager and add the Basic Auth header yourself:

#### Manually Encoding Credentials

- From MacOS or Linux:

  `echo -n "username:password" | base64`
- From Windows:

  Go [here](http://www.base64decode.org) and encode your "username:password" string

#### Adding the Authorization Header

In the HTTP Header Manager, add an entry with the name "Authorization" and the value "Basic [encoded credentials from above]"

Comment: holy crap, thx for your answer.  It worked for me, although, my only complaint is you need to dumb down your answer for guys like myself ;)  I didn't initially understand what you were telling us to do but luckily thru trial and error and re-reading your answer, somehow stumbled to the correct commands.

Comment: I use Postman for my initial testing.  I just copied their Authorization header & the encoded value and put that into a HTTP Header Manager.  It's nice to know there's a website out there that will do the encoding for you though!

Comment: Works for me too. @Depy, pls mark this answer as solution.

Answer (score 49):

**Edit 19 august 2017 for JMeter 3.2**:

- Use answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12563623/460802

Basically to bypass a Basic Authorization you need to add the **Authorization** header with the value **Basic base64(username:password)**. The problem is that JMeter has no base64 function embedded.

The solution is :

**Step1** Add *BeanShell PreProcessor* (PreProcessor --> BeanShell Preprocessor)

[image]

**Step2** Add the following script to the PreProcessor

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
byte[] encodedUsernamePassword = Base64.encodeBase64("neo4j:1234".getBytes());
vars.put("base64HeaderValue",new String(encodedUsernamePassword));
```

[image]

**Step3** Add HTTP Header Manager

[image]

**Step4** Add Authorization header with correct value

header name **Authorization** 
header value **Basic ${base64HeaderValue}**  (base64HeaderValue variable is initialized by the BeanShell Preprocessor)

[image]

So in the end when you create a http request Authorization header will be passed to the server with base64 encoded string

[image]

Comment: It works for me and its a great answer with many pictures :-). Thank you!

Comment: thanks for effort you took to post this detailed answer

Comment: Not needed anymore since JMeter 3.2, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12563623/460802

Answer (score 11):

Do the following:

- 1/ Configure [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) correctly with all required fields
- 2/ 
  Option 1 : **Using HTTP 4 :** (default)
- it is possible since JMeter 3.2 without any further configuration using Authorization Manager

Option 2 : **Using HTTP 3.1 :** (deprecated)

- in jmeter.properties , uncomment:

  ```
  httpclient.parameters.file=httpclient.parameters
  ```
- in httpclient.parameters, uncomment:

  ```
  http.authentication.preemptive$Boolean=true
  ```

If you're looking to learn JMeter, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) by 3 developers of the project will help you

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to provide a protocol for the base URL, i.e.: "http://localhost" instead of "localhost"

Comment: That was why it was not working for me. I copied the base URL from my HTTP request where it also works without giving the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Like Ryan T said, in the HTTP Header Manager, add an entry with the name `"Authorization"` and the value `"Basic [encoded credentials from above]"` but without `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you get Response code as 401, then add "HTTP Authorization manager" Config Element
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am using Jmeter 3.3

GO to Jmeter on User choose add then HTTP Authorization Manager

[image]

Then add ur url , userid,password

[image]

If response type is json then add HTTP Header manager

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use **JSON Extractor** for authentication inside the auth request to store the token in a variable, then you will just need to use it whenever the **token** is needed, in order to use that you will need an **HTTP header manager** using that variable you can follow the screenshots for clear instructions.

**JSON Extractor configuration:**
[image: JSON Extractor]
**HTTP header manager configuration:**
[image: HTTP header manager]

Answer (score 0):

Adding a slight variation of @yurko which uses the username & password from User defined variables. (for Jmeter prior to 3.2)

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
String username = vars.get("USERNAME");
String password = vars.get("PASSWORD");
String combineduserpass = username + ":" + password;
byte[] encodedUsernamePassword = Base64.encodeBase64(combineduserpass.getBytes());
vars.put("base64HeaderValue",new String(encodedUsernamePassword));
```

Comment: Not needed anymore since JMeter 3.2, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12563623/460802

Comment: Thanks for that!  I haven't updated mine in several months.  I'm so glad they made this easier.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to the first answer above, the incorrect encoding problem you mention must be now fixed, as Apache 3.1 does appear to encode the username:password correctly in HTTP Auth Manager

Comment: Yes, I am using _JMeter 3.2_ and I only added the clear username and password in the 'HTTP Basic Authentication' which **converts automatically** to the standard _'Authorization Basic [base64 encoded username:password]'_ in the HTTP header.

Comment: Not needed anymore since JMeter 3.2, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12563623/460802

Answer (score -1):

Updating good findings from your 2013 answers:

**The HTTP4 option also works under current Jmeter version 2.13**
after adding HTTP Header Manager row containing:

```
name="Authorization", value="Basic [base64-encoded user/password string]"
```

*Verified on current host amazon linux having reverse proxy from apache 2.4 to tomcat8; tomcat8 recognized the user credentials instead of throwing 401 status.*