# Pre-emptive auth with JMeter and HTTPClient 4

Tags: jmeter, basic-authentication

Using JMeter 2.9

Following this: [JMeter Basic Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560494/jmeter-basic-authentication)

For HTTP Client 3 it works.

But for HTTP Client 4 it doesn't seem to send the header.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a duplicate as in HTTP Client 4 doesn't send the header at all. I print the headers received in the server and with 4.x it doesn't show up.

Comment: What I was saying is that this question was a duplicate of JMeter Basic Authentication , there was a mistake in my answer which I fixed regardinf HttpClient 4

Comment: Ok I get it :) I upvoted your answer.