# JMeter Basic Authentication with HTTP Authorization Manager

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to do Basic Authentication for protected endpoints. I tried the following :

1. In the HTTP Header Manager, add an entry with the name "Authorization" and the value "Basic [encoded credentials from above]" as suggested in [JMeter Basic Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560494/jmeter-basic-authentication)
2. Added Http Authorization manager and added the 
   `base url as https://shopping-qa.myproject.mydomain.com`along with the username and password. The url of the endpoint is `https://shopping-qa.myproject.mydomain.com/api/v3/profile/summary`.

While it works when I use the option 1, it does not work when I use option 2. I also uncommented `httpclient.parameters.file=httpclient.parameters` in `jmeter.Properties` and `http.authentication.preemptive$Boolean=true` in `httpclient.parameters`. But I still do not get the authentication to work.

Any suggestions on where I am going wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `httpclient.parameters` - make sure that you have HTTPClient3 implementation of the HTTP Request Sampler(s).

Double check that HTTP Authorization Manager really adds "Authorization" header and credentials are correct.

See [How to use HTTP Basic Authentication in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) for example of bypassing basic HTTP authentication in phpmyadmin.