# Jmeter with basic authentication

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to run a loadtest on a RestAPI which I can access via below java

```
        name = "username";
        String password = "password";
        String authString = name + ":" + password;
        byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(authString.getBytes()); //
        String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
```

But in jmeter I am not able add this, new to jmeter please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since JMeter 3.2, Basic Auth is provided Out Of The Box using HttpClient4 implementation and configured by default, see:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57242
- http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html

> HTTP HC4 Implementation now provides preemptive Basic Auth enabled by default

Just add [HTTP_Authorization_Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) and fill in required information.

Example:

- For this request to "http://localhost:8081" :

[image]

- Configuration will be:

[image]

This configuration will match any request starting with "http://localhost:8081"

See also this question:

- [JMeter Basic Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560494/jmeter-basic-authentication/)

**Although my answer is downvoted for I don't know which reason, it is the best way to setup Basic Auth. Scripting is no more required at all since 3.2.**

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same code to generate the encoded credentials:

1. Add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) as a child of the relevant HTTP Request sampler
2. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) as a child of the relevant HTTP Request sampler
3. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   name = "username";
   String password = "password";
   String authString = name + ":" + password;
   byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(authString.getBytes()); //
   String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
   sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc));
   ```
4. Check `Cache compiled script if available` box

JMeter should now add the necessary "Authorization" header to your request.

[image: JMeter Basic Authentication]

Comment: Why was this voted down?  Worked for me when the official JMeter auth manager didn't.  Add "vars.get("appPassword");" if you don't want to hardcode passwords.

Comment: Well explaind solution. Thank you.