# Base64 Authentication Username and password

Tags: authentication, jmeter

I have been able to write a python script to get Base 64 auth for my username and password (Admin:password) equal to --> Basic QWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=
When I add that to my header manager as: 
Authorization  Basic QWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=
all my HTTP Requests succeed.

---

in Jmeter I have googled and I find to add below in Bean PreProcessor:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
String username = vars.get("Username");
String password = vars.get("Password");
String combineduserpass = username + ":" + password;
byte[] encodedUsernamePassword =         
Base64.encodeBase64(combineduserpass.getBytes());
vars.put("base64HeaderValue",new String(encodedUsernamePassword));
```

System.out.println(encodedUsernamePassword);

but that system output gives me --> [B@558e816b  which is incorrect

when I add that to my Header manager like this

Authorization  Basic ${base64HeaderValue}

my HTTP Req obviously fails. The Base64 for "Admin:password should really be Basic QWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=  and not  [B@558e816b

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print byte array. You can print the new variable as:

```
 System.out.println(vars.get("base64HeaderValue"));
```

Also your Header Manager should be **under** your HTTP Request so it be execute aftet script and before your request

Instead of scrpting you can use JMeter plugin of custom functions and use inside Header manager the [__base64Encode](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) function similar to:

```
  ${__base64Encode(test string, base64HeaderValue)}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do Basic Auth, just add [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) to your plan as per this answer:

- [JMeter Basic Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560494/jmeter-basic-authentication/12563623#12563623)

It would be configured like this if your server URL is **http://localhost:8080/test**:

[image: Http Authorization Manager]

There is no need for scripting here.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend switching to [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and Groovy language as:

1. Groovy supports all modern Java language features including (but not limited to)

   - [encoding byte arrays into Base64](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/primitive-types/byte.html#encodeBase64())
   - [decoding Base64 strings](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#decodeBase64())
2. [Groovy performance is way better comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Groovy equivalent of your code would be:

```
vars.put('base64HeaderValue',(vars.get('Username') + ':' + vars.get('Password')).bytes.encodeBase64().toString())
```